# Why does add_filter with a redirect cause an infinite redirect loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I can see how the below code is problematic but not why it would result in an redirect loop?

// Redirect user based on Location_cookie

```
add_filter( 'after_setup_theme', 'ip_redirect_on_cloudflare', 1);
function ip_redirect_on_cloudflare()
{
    $CFCountry = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY'];

    switch ($CFCountry){
        case "SE":
            wp_redirect( 'https://tidanapp.com/shop/sv/' );
            exit;   
    }
}
```

Comment: So what happens when the country is `SE`? It redirects. Is this code also invoked on the `/sv/` version? Why shouldn't the redirect happen in that case?

Comment: Try to use a break instead of an exit function. That way you stop cycling around a loop pointlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like:

```
add_filter( 'after_setup_theme', 'ip_redirect_on_cloudflare', 1);
function ip_redirect_on_cloudflare()
{
    $current_country = ''; // get current country from your multilanguage plugin
    $CFCountry = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY'];

    if(strtolower($current_country) != strtolower($CFCountry)) {
      switch ($CFCountry){
        case "SE":
            wp_redirect( 'https://tidanapp.com/shop/sv/' );
            exit;   
      }
    }
}
```

Or if you cannot get the current country/language from the plugin you are using you could check based on the URL (which is not the nicest option):

```
add_filter( 'after_setup_theme', 'ip_redirect_on_cloudflare', 1);
function ip_redirect_on_cloudflare()
{
    $CFCountry = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY'];

    switch ($CFCountry){
      case "SE":
          if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/sv/') === false) {
              wp_redirect( 'https://tidanapp.com/shop/sv/' );
          }
            exit;   
    }
}
```